# visual studio selection not in blue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am using visual studio 2005 for c++ this summer, but I am still not very familiar with it.

Initially when I selected something the background of the selected text would change to blue, but now it is not changing.

Can someone tell me how I change this to show the blue background when selecting text again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VS2005 in front of me, but I'm quite sure it's the same: go to the Tools menu, select Options, and then Fonts and Colors under Environment. In the middle, under Display items, click Selected Text. Then, change the Item background setting to that blue you like.

[image]